# Create a calculated column using data from two tables in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

In the order table I want to add a column called amount that its content is calculated automatically by multiplying Pedido.cant of the Pedido table by the Producto.precio of the Producto table

Table Producto

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT exists Producto (
idfab INT NOT NULL,
idproducto INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (idfab, idproducto),
descripcion VARCHAR(100),
precio INT,
existencias INT
);
```

Table Pedido

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT exists Pedido (
numpedido INT primary key auto_increment,
fechapedido DATE NOT NULL,
clie INT,
resp INT NOT NULL,
fab INT NOT NULL,
producto INT NOT NULL,
cant INT
);
```

**Example:**

```
+-------+------------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| idfab | idproducto | descripcion | precio | existencias |
+-------+------------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| 1     | 1          | TV          | 7      | 2000        |
+-------+------------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| 1     | 2          | Radio       | 5      | 2000        |
+-------+------------+-------------+--------+-------------+
| 2     | 1          | Lamp        | 12     | 200         |
+-------+------------+-------------+--------+-------------+
```

Table Pedido

```
+-----------+-------------+------+------+-----+----------+------+---------+
| numpedido | fechapedido | clie | resp | fab | producto | cant | importe |
+-----------+-------------+------+------+-----+----------+------+---------+
| 1         | 2000-10-10  | 1    | 2    | 1   | 1        | 100  | 700     |
+-----------+-------------+------+------+-----+----------+------+---------+
| 2         | 1999-05-05  | 1    | 2    | 1   | 2        | 20   | 100     |
+-----------+-------------+------+------+-----+----------+------+---------+
| 3         | 2001-07-10  | 2    | 1    | 1   | 1        | 10   | 120     |
+-----------+-------------+------+------+-----+----------+------+---------+
```

Comment: You should either translate the columns or use Spanish/Portuguese names.  There is no "quantity" in an "orders" table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry I had used the google translator and I had not realized

Comment: If you mean generated columns then 'Subqueries are not permitted.' - etc https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html only expressions are permitted using columns from the same table and even then they must be deterministic. Consider a trigger or just include calculation in query when need be